# azure devops qt integration pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm setting up my first pipeline job in azure devops.  My C++ application uses the QT framework with qmake to create the make files.  It also makes heavy use of the QT framework.

I'd like to use the Microsoft managed ubuntu server.  How do I get the QT open source framework and tools installed on the build server?  Or, do I have to use a self-managed server?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the supported Software packages in Ubuntu 1604 image at [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1604-README.md). So as per the official docs QT is not supported by the Ubuntu hosted agent,which means you have to use your own custom agent for the build.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was beginning to suspect.

Comment: @WildaHunden happy to help.Please accept my answer, so that it would be helpful to other community members. Thanks

Comment: You can log an issue on that linked github requesting it added to the image also.